# What packages are there for Azure MSAL for React Native?

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, azure-authentication

I've been looking for packages to use to enable MS Auth in a React Native app.

One feature we would like is to automatically authenticate the user once they have logged in (possibly from another app or website).

I have found `react-native-msal` but it hasn't been updated in the last 2 years and their github repo is archived.

Also does `@azure/msal-react` supposed work with React Native?

Are there any recent packages out there that allows this functionality next to SSO?

Comment: Any OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect library will work. MSAL libraries are built on top of these standards.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option at this point will be to:

1. Use any other OpenID Connect OAuth Library, Microsoft’s APIs are standards compliant, you can use other libraries and work with Microsoft. I use https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth
2. Take the react-native-msal and try and use it. If there are issues you will have to update the code and make it work.
3. You can use we WebView to handle the authentication flow. This method isn’t the most native-feeling, but it can be effective. After authentication, you can store tokens securely (e.g., using react-native-sensitive-info) and use them for subsequent requests.

Comment: we use `react-native-app-auth` at the moment but it does not support auto login when the user used another linked app... I guess we will go with WebView

Comment: Hey just as an update we are using Webview login with MS AD. Once one logs in, the in-app browser stores the cookies while we also get tokens and all the stuff we want with some API calls. Then since the in-app browser stores the cookies as long as the app is open all other webviews authenticated automatically by MS-AD login forms.

Comment: Hello, what are you using now in 2024 ? 

Thank you